# Python/Numpy: How do you assign the end+1 element of an array similar to how it's done in Matlab?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

For example, for a 1D array with n elements, if I want to do this in Matlab I can do:

A(end+1) = 1

that assigns the value of 1 to the last element of array A which is now n+1 in length.

Is there an equivalent in Python/Numpy?

Comment: Would `A.append(1)` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just append a value to the end of an array/list using `append` or `numpy.append`:

```
# Python list
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.append(1)
# => [1, 2, 3, 1]

# Numpy array
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a = np.append(a, 1)
# => [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Note, as pointed out by @BrenBarn, that the `numpy.append` approach creates a whole new array each time it is executed, which makes it inefficient.

Comment: Note that this is an inefficient operation, since it creates a whole new array.  Gradually increasing the size of numpy arrays is not a scalable approach.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Agreed, I updated my answer to make that readily apparent.

Comment: `np.append` is just a `np.concatenate`.

Comment: As inefficient as Matlab's `end+1`, so that's appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I bet the Matlab/Octave operation does the same - create a new object. But I don't know if there is something like the Python id(a) to verify that.

A crude timing test in Octave supports this - creating a large array by appending is slower than stepping through the full array.  Both are much slower than direct assignment like `A=1:N`

```
octave:36> t=time; N=1000000; A=[]; A(N)=1; for i=1:N A(i)=i; end; t-time
ans = -4.0374
octave:37> t=time; N=1000000; A=[]; for i=1:N A(end+1)=i; end; t-time
ans = -15.218
```

Extending an array with `(end+1)` is more idiomatic in Javascript than Matlab.

Comment: In the latest versions of Matlab, the JIT is sometimes smart enough to recognize this pattern and do some preallocation.